# How to make it more generic this for loop with generics?

Tags: java, loops, generics

These are classes of my project. 
The class Bean is a super type of Employe and Computer and not is intanziable.

```
abstract Class Bean{
   private HashMap<String, String> fields = null;
   protected Bean(Map<String, Object> row) {
        //fill HashMap fields
   }
}
public class Employe extends Bean {
    public Employe (Map<String, Object> row) {
        super(row);
   }
}

public class Computer extends Bean {
    public Computer (Map<String, Object> row) {
        super(row);
    }
}
```

How to make it more generic this for loop with generics ?

I would write the two cycles below once using generics in a utility method riusable.

```
//Loop 1

List<Map<String, Object>> employeRows = //from query on database

List<Employe> employList = new ArrayList<Employe>();

for (Map<String, Object> row : employeRows) {
    Employe e = new Employe(row);
    employList .add(e);
}

//Loop 2

List<Map<String, Object>> computerRows = //from query on database

List<Computer> computerList = new ArrayList<Computer>();

for (Map<String, Object> row : computerRows ) {
    Computer c = new Computer(row);
    computerList.add(c);
}
```

This pseudo-code is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
List<Employe> = Utility.toList(employeRows, ...);
List<Computer> = Utility.toList(computerList, ...);
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? What do you mean by making it more generic?

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Java 7 or below, factory pattern is the way to go. But if you're already on Java 8, you can achieve this with streams and lambda / method reference.

Here's how you do it with Java 8:

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(List<Map<String, Object>> rows, Function<Map<String, Object>, T> mapper) {
    return rows.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then call this method by passing the constructor as method reference:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> employeRows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
List<Map<String, Object>> computerRows = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

List<Employe> employList = toList(employeRows, Employe::new);
List<Computer> computerList = toList(computerRows, Computer::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Factory Pattern, one abstract factory

```
interface ObjectCreater<T> {
  T create(Map<String, Object> row);
}
```

and two Implementations, e.g. for Employee

```
class EmployeeCreater implements ObjectCreator<T> {
  T create(Map<String, Object> row) {
     return new Employee(row); // or the constructor logic inlined
  }
}
```

define a method (= Utility.toList()):

```
List<T> toList(List<Map<String, Object>> row, ObjectCreator<T> creator) {
  // the upper loop using the factory instead of the Constructor
}
```